# How do I load a SQlite Database into Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have a recyclerview inside a fragment activity that uses a button to bring up an alert dialog box to get input for 2 string variables. I have successfully created the database and can add items to the database from the alertdialog input, but I want to populate the recyclerview with the database when the app initially starts up. The database is used to store the input and I want it to populate the recyclerview so the user can see the items they entered previously.

This is my fragment:

```
public class tab1Expenses extends Fragment {

SqlDatabase dbEntry;

ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ExpensesAdapter mAdapter;
Button btnEx;
String Na;
String Am;
String message = "Name must be longer than 2 characters";
String message2 = "Please enter valid amount";
Double value;
String am;

public void expenseData() {
    ExRow exs = new ExRow(Na, Am);
    expenseList.add(exs);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
    btnEx = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEx);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    mAdapter = new ExpensesAdapter(expenseList);
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setClickable(true);
    recyclerView.isFocusable();
    recyclerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Brings up Alert Dialog when Add income button is pressed
            add();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


public int add() {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
    final EditText txtExName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exName);
    final EditText txtExAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.exAmount);
    //Creates Alert Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity());
    add.setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Add",
                    //AlertDialog positive button ClickListener
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Checks for invalid input
                            //If criteria met, expenseData() is called
                            if (txtExAmount.getText().length() > 0 && txtExName.getText().length() > 2 && txtExAmount.getText().length() < 6 && txtExName.getText().length() < 25) {
                                Na = txtExName.getText().toString();
                                am = txtExAmount.getText().toString();
                                value = Double.parseDouble(am);
                                Am = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value);
                                expenseData();

                            }
                            //Toast for invalid input
                            if (txtExName.getText().length() <= 2) {
                                Toast.makeText(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (txtExAmount.getText().length() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity(), message2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (txtExAmount.getText().length() >= 6) {
                                Toast.makeText(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity(), "You don't make that much", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (txtExName.getText().length() >= 25) {
                                Toast.makeText(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity(), "Name must be less than 25 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
    Dialog dialog = add.create();
    dialog.show();

    return 0;
}

public void viewAll() {

        ExRow exrow = new ExRow();
        Cursor res = dbEntry.getAllData();
        exrow.setTitle(res.getString(1));
        exrow.setAmount(res.getString(2));

  }
}
```

This is my database:

```
public class SqlDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Expenses.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Expense_Table";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String Col_NAME = "Na";
public static final String Col_AMOUNT = "Am";


    public SqlDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    //Set up database here
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME +
                "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT, AMOUNT TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String Na, String Am) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Col_NAME, Na);
        contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT, Am);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
public static Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;

}
}
```

And this is my RecyclerView Adapter + View holder:

```
public class ExpensesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpensesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
public ImageButton mRemoveButton;
private ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, amount;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        mRemoveButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
    }
}

public ExpensesAdapter(ArrayList<ExRow> expenseList) {
    this.expenseList = expenseList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.expense_list, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position
) {

    ExRow expense = expenseList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    holder.title.setText(expense.getTitle());
    holder.amount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the item on remove/button click
            int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            expenseList.remove(adapterPosition);
            notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return expenseList.size();
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get List of your **ExRow** instead of cursor in your SQLiteOpenHelper. So instead of:

```
public static Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;

}
```

You need to return List with something like this:

```
// Your column 
private String[] allColumns = { "ID", "COLUMN_1", "COLUMN_2" };

public List<ExRow> getAllData() {
    List<ExRow> exrows = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query("YOUR_TABLE", allColumns, null, null, 
                                   null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        ExRow exrow = populateModel(cursor);
        exrows.add(exrow);
        cursor.moveToNext();
      }
      cursor.close();
    }
    return exrows;
  }


 private ExRow populateModel(Cursor c) {
    ExRow model = new ExRow();
    model.setId(c.getLong("ID"));
    model.setColumn1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_1")));
    model.setColumn2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_2")));

    return model;
 }
```

Then you can use the value returned from `getAllData()` and pass it to your Adapter.

Comment: no, he needs a `Cursor` aware adapter, like the one in my comment above

Comment: If we look at the op SQLite helper, then you're correct. But if we look at op Adapter, we can conclude that List is the op answer. I don't think it's a good advice to recreate op adapter.

Comment: It is not a good idea to duplicate your data, what do you need `exrows` for if your data is already stored in the `Cursor`?

Comment: This is my first time using recyclerviews and sqlite databases in an app so I don't know my way around Cursors. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @Corpse then use `Cursor` aware adapter,like `CursorRecyclerAdapter`, you will save a lot of time then

Comment: To use a cursor adapter, do i need a new class for it or can it be implemented into my recyclerview adapter?

Comment: @Corpse just extend `CursorRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: Would I need to do anything in my fragment?

Comment: `"encapsulation and decoupling code maybe?"`, no it is simply data duplicating, nothing more

Comment: Here a simple case to support my arguments: Imagine that op want to change the table columns names. Op then need to change the Adapter. Or if op decide to use data from the network. So op need to recreate his adapter again. Or if op didn't have a direct access for the database name and table.

Instead of arguing with me, it's a wise step if you make an answer that describe and clarify your recommendation to op.